# How to parse a DateTime string based on culture?

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Well I was creating a application for windows phone 8.1 WinRT. 
I save a **Datetime.now() based on en-US** culture initially but later the culture gets changed and when I try to parse the saved string in `DateTime.Parse()`, I get a **format exception**.

```
//Setting en-US culture
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;

//Saving DateTime.Now in a string format
String usTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

//Changing it to the de-DE culture
culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;

//Now trying to parse the usTime
DateTime deTime = DateTime.Parse(usTime);
//Here I get an error saying format exception.
```

Is there anyway I can tell it how to parse and convert usTime string to deTime DateTime?

Comment: This way ? DateTime.TryParse(dtstring, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("xxxx"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)

Comment: What is the value of `usTime` and what is your `CurrentCulture` exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an `IFormatProvider` to [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var cultureUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");

//Now trying to parse the usTime with US culture format provider
DateTime deTime = DateTime.Parse(usTime, cultureUS);
```