# C# proper convert string to datetime to SetLastWriteTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to compare files on my server with my program files and update them if needed. If I use a HttpWebResponse .LastModified it takes much longer than if I were to make a PHP files with the modify times in them and just read that.

Only problem I have is when I read the string from the server and try to convert it to a datetime object it doesn't want to set the file's modify time to it using SetLastWriteTime. How should I properly convert my string to a datetime for SetLastWriteTime to work?

My server's date/time string example: 1/29/2016 11:19:48 AM

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Are you wondering how to parse a string as DateTime? `DateTime.Parse("1/29/2016 11:19:48 AM")`

Comment: Use en-US culture; this might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105593/how-to-parse-a-datetime-string-based-on-culture

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking", as you appear to be talking about four or five different things and haven't connected the dots very well.  What files are being compared? What exactly takes "too long" and what do you mean by that. What's PHP got to do with it?  Why are you working with strings at all?  If you want good advice, then you'll have to be much more clear about exactly what you are doing.  Though you answered your own question (which is fine), this is certainly an example of [an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: comparing a file on my server, to a local file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDateTime("1/29/2016 11:19:48 AM");
```

This ended up working.

Comment: Be careful, a string like `"1/7/2016"` could be interpreted as either January 7th, or July 1st - depending on the culture settings.